# c# How to add a row in specific DatagridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am using a TabControl placed in the main form.
I have added TabPage1 and TabPage2.
Any `TabPage` contains `DatagridView1`, `DatagridView2` and `DatagridView3`.
I'd like to insert a row in a specific `DataGidView` (i.e. DatagridView2).

```
// This code works for TabPage2

this.DatagridView2.Rows.Insert(0, temp_row);
```

How to add a row to TabPage2, DatagridView1?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve? - What stops you from using DatagridView1.Rows.Insert(0, temp_row);

Comment: I have DataGridView1 in TabPage 1 and DataGridView1 in TabPage2.

Comment: If you add a row to DataGridView1, it will reflect that added row in all the tab pages, since it is the same object.  If you want them to reflect different items, then you need to create and populate them separately.  But, I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, assuming I have created all tabPage object, how I can select the specific TabPage and DataGridView in order to add the row?